# Passing a label control to JavaScript and setting its value

Tags: javascript, vb.net, parameters

I have a VB.NET page that uses a master page. I have a JavaScript function that performs a task and updates an aspx label value using the innerHTML:

*lbl = document.getElementById('<%=lblCount.ClientID %>');
...
lbl.innerHTML = "some text";*

This works fine. But, I want to be able to pass the label control as a parameter to the JavaScript function, as there are different labels that may need to be updated.

I'd like to pass the label control as below, but it doesn't work. What's the proper way of passing the aspx label control and accessing it within JavaScript?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeypress="return myFunc(lblX)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblX" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

> function myFunc(lbl) {
>         lbl.innerHTML = 'some text';
>             --or-- 
>         lbl.value = 'some text';
>         }

Comment: You had it already: `document.getElementById('<%=lblCount.ClientID %>')`... So `onkeypress="return myFunc(document.getElementById('<%=lblX.ClientID %>'));"`

Comment: The attribute is inside runat="server" control so nested <%= will not work. AFAIK

Comment: I had to use the format: document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentData_lblX') - the nested <%= didn't work. There's probably a more elegant solution, but for now, this will have to do. Thanks Heretic Monkey for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use codebehind? I would configure it in Page_Load event:

```
txt.Attributes("onkeypress")= String.Format("return myFunc('{0}');", lblX.ClientID)
```

Otherwise you'll need some onpage javascript to bind them together. Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeypress="return myFunc(this.labelID);"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblX" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID %>').labelID = '<%=lbl.ClientID %>';
</script>
```